# How to generate classes in jaxb from WSDL with HTTPS LINK?

Tags: web-services, maven, spring-mvc, https, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I need to consume a web service  from a third party. The WSDL is provided by the third party on a https link.I have tried to generate the classes using maven-jaxb2plugin but it gives me an error.I need to generate classes from a https link using maven-jaxb2plugin How can I achieve this using maven-jaxb2 plugin.
The error is as follows

```
    [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing           "https://localhost:8443/ws/countries.wsdl". Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:94)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:402)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:274)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:324)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:391)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:170)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:488)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:311)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:394)
... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building   failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
... 52 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 58 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.250 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-04T13:57:19-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/187M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate (default) on project ieals: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

How do I generate classes from https WSDL link in maven using jaxb plugin

Comment: make sure you have the certificates for accessing the site and add the certificate to your truststore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have SSL certificate of the third party added in your truststore to access https URLs. Please check the third party URL is correct, as the domain shown in your log is shownas "**localhost**". It should be some valid domain.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7 if i configure tomcat trustore is it enough as i have hosted the wsdl in localhost

Comment: You may have to modify tomcat's server.xml file to configure certificate keystore paths and https ports.

Comment: But I have already configured tomcat but when i try to build it using maven it gives me  error

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation to fix your HTTPS is sound. You seem to have two problems here:

- Your error points to `localhost` and somehow you're talking about configuring Tomcat and at the same time about "web service from a third party". `localhost` does not look like a third party to me.
- Java does not trust the certificate provided by your HTTPS server. Either your server is using some rogue self-signed certificate OR you may have an outdated JVM which, for instance does not have some new intermediate certs (like Letsencrypt). You have to fix this in your JDK either by an update or by importing the missing certificates into your store.

However, I generally don't recommend compiling schemas/WSDLs from online resources. You normally want clean reproducible builds not depending on the well being of some server out there. Make local copies of files your want to compile and [use catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs) to virtually point external URLs to your local copies. This will make your build independent of external resources.

Comment: Initially i did not have the third party certificate so i cloned the wsdl to my localhost server and then tried to access the wsdl with a different client running on localhost with different port number.How do I make jaxb generate classes from wsdl in local storage